# Try .... Catch is not giving all the errors in T-SQL execution

Tags: t-sql, try-catch, block

I am trying to restore a database from a backup using Try Catch block. In that I am using first restore file list and then restore backup using Move option. with Try ... Catch Block. Iam trying to catch those errors into a table with insert statement. In that table I am getting only one message...

**Restore Filelist terminating abnormally**

```
ErrorNumber ErrorSeverity ErrorState  ErrorProcedure  ErrorLine  ErrorMessage
----------- ------------- ----------- --------------- ---------- ----------------------------------
3013        16            1           NULL            1          RESTORE FILELIST is terminating abnormally..
```

but not the following message...

```
Msg 3201, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot open backup device '\\SQLBKUP\SQL Server\SQLInstance\DEFAULT\XYZ_9389451.bak'. 
Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
```

Any thoughts why I am NOT getting that error captured with the Catch Block?

Comment: It's probably because you have written your code wrong.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://sqlwithmanoj.com/2013/01/24/another-reason-to-use-throw-clause-instead-of-raiserror-sql-server-2012/) and [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1641090-1550-1.aspx). If a statement throws more than one exception you only `catch` the last one.

Comment: HABO... Thanks for the message. How can I catch THROW messages to a table in CATCH block?